# Cajas flex al 50% de la pantalla

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Usando divs con `display:flex` quisiera que los dos elementos que van a tener dentro ocupasen el 50% de la pantalla respectivamente, pero no lo consigo modificando la propiedad `flex-grow`. He probado a jugar un poco con los valores de dicha propiedad y nada.
Actualmente tengo el código

```css
    .cabecera{
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .item-flex{
      flex-grow: 50%; /* realizando pruebas */
    }
    .item-primero{background:yellow;}/*background pruebas*/
    .item-second{background:blue;}/*background pruebas*/
```

```html
<div class="cabecera">
  <div class="item-flex item-primero">
    este es mi item primero
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex item-second">
  este es mi segundo
  </div>
</div>
```

Para conseguirlo ¿qué tendría que jugar con la propiedad flex-basis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568572/flexbox-vertically-split-container-in-half) he visto la respuesta, y he copiado el `css -> flex: 0 1 50%;` en tu `item-flex`

```css
.cabecera{
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .item-flex{
      
      flex: 0 1 50%;


    }
    .item-primero{background:yellow;}/*background pruebas*/
    .item-second{
      background:blue;
     text-align: right;
     }/*background pruebas*/
```

```html
<div class="cabecera">
  <div class="item-flex item-primero">
    este es mi item primero
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex item-second">
  este es mi segundo
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Justo había encontrado también ahora cómo usarlo, muchas gracias! Ahora me surge una duda...el `item-segundo` habría forma de que su alineación sea a la derecha? Sería usar el `text-align:right;` ¿?

Comment: @Marcos si, he actualizado mi respuesta para que añada ese `css`. Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

Haciendo más pruebas creo que he encontrado con lo que buscaba.

Estaba aplicando la propiedad errónea, tenía que establecer a la caja la propiedad `flex-basis`.

El resultado queda así

```css
.cabecera{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:#FFF;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
.item-flex{
  flew-grow:1;
  flex-basis:46%;
  padding:0 2%;
}
.item-primero{
  background:yellow;
}
.item-second{
  background:grey;
  color:#FFF;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="cabecera">
  <div class="item-flex item-primero">
    este es mi item primero
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex item-second">
  este es mi segundo  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar `flex:1` y ese div tendra el ancho restante.
es decir si tu `.item-primero` tiene ancho 30%, el otro div tendra ancho 70%

```css
.cabecera{
  display:flex;
 }
   
  .item-primero{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.item-second{
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cabecera">
  <div class="item-flex item-primero">
    este es mi item primero
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex item-second">
  este es mi segundo
  </div>
</div>
```

> si hubiera 3 elementos y el primero fuera 50% , el segundo flex: 1y el
>   tercero flex: 1 ... significaria que quedarian 50% , 25% y 25% ?

```css
.cabecera{
  display:flex;
 }
   
  .item-primero{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.item-second{
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
  flex:1;
}
.item-tercer{
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cabecera">
  <div class="item-flex item-primero">
    este es mi item primero
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex item-second">
  este es mi segundo
  </div>
  <div class="item-flex item-tercer">
  este es mi tercer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: mola! si hubiera 3 elementos y el primero fuera `50%` , el segundo `flex: 1`y el tercero `flex: 1` ... significaria que quedarian `50% , 25% y 25%` ?

Comment: @lois6b ya edite mi respuesta, con un ejemplo de tu pregunta

Comment: niceee. gracias ^^ parece que mi logica no era enrebuscada xD

Comment: Uhm...estoy empezando a usar el tema del `display:flex` y viendo el código que usas @x-rw ¿por qué usar `float:left` en el 1º elemento? Quiero decir, en vez de aplicar también un `display:flex`

Comment: @Marcos simplemente es para posicionar al lado izquierdo, y `float:right` para el lado derecho

Comment: @Marcos te sirve mi respuesta, o te esta causando confusión?, necesitas mas explicacion?

Comment: Si, sirve @x-rw sólo que me ha extrañado el no aplicar ahí un `display:flex` para seguir digamos la "estructura" y usar un float ;)

Comment: @Marcos el `display:flex` lo puse en el contenedor principal `.cabecera{
  display:flex;
 }`

Comment: Perdona, quería decir un `flex: x x x` @x-rw ;)

Comment: @Marcos si hubiera usado eso mi respuesta seria relativamente una copia de otras que ya tienes, asi que mi respuesta es una alternativa de solucion

Answer (score 0):

Sí que puedes lograrlo con "flex-grow", pero estableciéndolo en el atajo "flex". Quedaría de esta forma.

```
.item-flex{
    flex: 1;
}
```

Al usar flex-grow de esta manera, el valor numérico viene a actuar como un valor con unidad fr, pero sin ella. Si se presenta el caso en que quieres distribuir desigualmente el espacio, asignando un 66.6% a un lado y 33.3% al otro, puedes lograrlo con lo siguiente:

```
.elemento1 {
    flex: 2;
}
.elemento2 {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Así puedes ir variando los valores y espacios a distribuir.

Nótese que, al igual que cuando se usa fr, se suman los valores de todos los elementos que pertenecen a ese espacio con tal de calcular el total a repartir, y tomarán la parte que la propia propiedad indique. Para el ejemplo 66 y 33, el total a repartir son 3 partes, y el elemento1 tomará 2 de ellas, mientras que el elemento2 tomará solo 1.